# When pairing a bluetooth keyboard(-like) device with Yosemite, can the pin number be skipped?

Tags: macos, bluetooth

I ordered one of these [Vicro Technilogy Ltd. Bluetooth Mini GamePad (PA-BK11)](http://vicro.cn/ProductDetail.aspx?ColumnId=66&ArticleId=643&Language=36&Terminal=41) ’s off of Amazon.

[image: Mini gamepad on keychain]

It shows up as “Bluetooth Gamepad” in the Bluetooth system preferences panel, with a keyboard icon. I can click “pair,” at which point it asks me to type in a 6 digit number.

Is there a trick to making it pair without entering the requested PIN number? Having no luck Googling this one. There are one or two articles on accomplishing the same in Linux, but nothing for Mac.

The controller is not anything special, but it’s small enough to fit in my kids’ hands when they play Nintendo games, something that none of the other controllers can do even if they do pair correctly.

[edit] I've since tried this with a newer (2014) iMac at work. Though both it and my own computer (2009 model) use Yosemite, the 2014 iMac doesn't require a pin to be typed in. According to Apple.com, my Mac has Bluetooth 2.1.

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to connect to a cheap Chinese play/pause button using `blueutil` on Big Sur. Just use `blueutil --connect ID` without pairing it first. After a couple of tries it started working.

Comment: This did the trick for my 8bitdo zero 2 (in keyboard mode for use with Scratch). I started it in keyboard mode, then set it to pairing mode, then ran `blueutil --inquiry 3` to get the id then `blueutil --connect (ID)` and `blueutil --pair (ID)` a bunch of times. Eventually macos popped up the "Keyboard Setup Assistant" instead of the password prompt. I marked it as ANSI and I was in business!

Answer (score 1):

You mention a “6 digit number” but from what I understand about how Bluetooth gamepads pair in Mac OS X it should be a 4 digit PIN.

Regardless, you can enter any series of digits from your main system keyboard and it should work. Try something like `0000`/`000000` or `1234`/`123456` and it should be able to pair without issue.

Comment: You see the picture I included. There are no number keys. Just the buttons, and if they map to any numeric key, I've been unable to determine that.

Comment: If I try that, I just hear the "thwuck" sound for each keystroke. No luck.

Answer (score 0):

So I had a similar problem with the BK3001BA Keyboard. I am not sure if this will work given I could enter the information but it would not pair correctly when I entered the correct pin.

Regardless, I opened Bluetooth File Transfer, and connected to my keyboard to send a file, and it connected this time. Try that and give it a go. Maybe by some chance it will work.